# SignUp throws error in StackExchange.com for the non logged-in user

Tags: bug, status-completed, stackexchange.com, sign-up

After the top bar changes in the [StackExchange.com](https://stackexchange.com), when a **non logged-in** user click the Sign Up button, instead of navigating to the corresponding page it displays the openid related code in the screen.

Screenshots for reference:

[image: Sign Up button]

[image: When clicked the Sing Up]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry about that. I completely forgot about it when we were rolling out the new topbar on stackexchange.com, but signup works entirely differently there than it does on Q&A. We AJAX in the Stack Exchange OpenID signup form, and guess which route provided the URL to do so... :)

The issue is fixed in production now. Thanks for the report!