# No sign up button on stackexchange.com homepage

Tags: feature-request, design, stackexchange.com

I just created my account. On the web (desktop) version there was no "Sign Up" button anywhere. I had to "Log in" and "Forgot password" to get to a page where I could sign up. I'm on Firefox 74.0 for Linux.
[image: No sign-up button on the Stack Exchange website on Firefox for desktop]

Comment: You're actually correct, there is no "Sign up" button from [the top-level Stack Exchange page](https://stackexchange.com). There is a sign-up button on every other site on the network's top right corner, however. My guess is because you can't necessarily have a network account without being a part of at least one site on the network itself, but I could be wrong.

Comment: @Spevacus That's exactly my suspicion as well.

Comment: Well, I'll leave a suggestion to include a Sign Up button there too. I mean, there's a Log in button, they might as well choose a "default" site to sign up to from the top-level page. Don't know how important this is, it just caught my attention.

Comment: It's a fair question, I've voted to reopen. I'm not sure if it's a bug per se, but it's definitely a bit strange to not have some way of signing up directly from the SE home page.

Comment: Well, there [used to be such a button](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/303312/signup-throws-error-in-stackexchange-com-for-the-non-logged-in-user), so this question should be changed to a feature request, asking to undo the change.